# How do I comfortably use CGColor in an NSArray with CGGradient

Tags: iphone, ios, nsarray, uicolor

I have two UIColor instances and want to use them creating a gradient. The code works, but it gives me a warning when I call the `arrayWithObject:` constructor:

> warning: Semantic Issue: Incompatible
>   pointer types sending 'CGColorRef'
>   (aka 'struct CGColor *') to parameter
>   of type 'id'

I suspect there lurks other issues related to the warning (leaks for instance). Here is the snippet:

```
   UIColor *startColor, *endColor; 
   // ...
   NSArray *colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                      startColor.CGColor, endColor.CGColor, nil];
   CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColors(colorSpace, 
                     (CFArrayRef) colors, NULL);
```

*How can I rewrite the code to get rid of this warning in a safe way ?*

- I tried creating a CGArrayRef manually, but that got a bit nasty after a while.
- [CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/Reference/CGGradient/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004880-CH1g-DontLinkElementID_2) works, but I don't like having to manually merge all color components into an `CGFloat components[]`

Comment: can you make use of `CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
 gradient.frame = view.bounds;
 gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor], (id)[[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor], nil];`

Comment: @7KV7, I don't think so. I use this in drawRect to create my filled shape (which is a non-rectangular polygon btw).

Comment: Also UIColor *startColor, endColor;  should be UIColor *startColor, *endColor;

Comment: I have removed the warning with the code in my answer. See if it works.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try this

```
UIColor *startColor, *endColor; 
   // ...
   NSArray *colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                      (id)startColor.CGColor, (id)endColor.CGColor, nil];
   CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColors(colorSpace, 
                     (CFArrayRef) colors, NULL);
```