# Creating an Array of CGColors from an Array of UIColors or NSColors

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, cagradientlayer, cgcolor

I've been testing `CAGradientLayer` to create gradient colors for iOS and Mac OS X (Cocoa).  For example, I have the following lines of code to create gradient colors for iOS.

```
let gradient: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
gradient.frame = view.bounds
gradient.colors = [UIColor.orangeColor().CGColor,UIColor.redColor().CGColor]
gradient.locations = [0.1,0.9]
self.view.layer.insertSublayer(gradient,atIndex:0)
```

Now, what I have is an array of colors (`UIColor` or `NSColor`), depending on the development platform.  If I create an array containing `UIColor` (or `NSColor`) objects programmatically, starting with

```
var cArray = [UIColor]()
```

or

```
var cArray = [NSColor]()
```

, how can I create an array containing CGColors with them?  I'm thinking that [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5948237/how-do-i-comfortably-use-cgcolor-in-an-nsarray-with-cggradient) might be related.  One problem is that I don't know how to declare and initialize an array of CGColor objects.

Thank you

Comment: You could use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24065017/how-to-determine-device-type-from-swift-os-x-or-ios to know on which platform you are, and possibly an object that would handle the correct color: `MyCustomObjectColor.redColor().CGColor`

Comment: What about a simple map: `let cgcolors = uicolors.map { $0.CGColor }` ? – Also consider to use `SKColor` as a platform-independent alias to either `UIColor` or `NSColor`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do:

```
extension _ArrayType where Generator.Element == UIColor {
    func CGColors() -> [CGColorRef] {
        var cgColorArray: [CGColorRef] = []

        for color in self {
            cgColorArray.append(color.CGColor)
        }

        return cgColorArray
    }
}
```

Use it like so:

```
let colors: [UIColor] = [UIColor.redColor(), UIColor.orangeColor()]
colors.CGColors()
```

Repeat for NSColor.

Comment: Thanks.  But how are you going to declare and initialize an array of CGColor objects?

Comment: `var cgColorArray: [CGColorRef] = []`

Comment: Oops, sorry...  Right...  I get an error at return cgColorArray, though.

Comment: I only need to know how to declare and initialize a CGColor array, I guess.  Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I would also like to give the function `map` some attention.

```
    let colors: [UIColor] = [UIColor.redColor(), UIColor.orangeColor()]
    let cgColors: [CGColor] = colors.map({ $0.CGColor })
```

`map` applies the closure to every element in the array and returns it.

`$0` is the first (and only) parameter to the closure.

It's actually a shorthand for:

```
    let cgColors: [CGColor] = colors.map({ return $0.CGColor })
```

which is a shorthand for:

```
    let cgColors: [CGColor] = colors.map({
        color: in
        return color.CGColor
    })
```

which is a shorthand for:

```
    let cgColors: [CGColor] = colors.map({
        (color: UIColor) in
        return color.CGColor
    })
```

Comment: Okay.  Thank you for your showing me something new.  But I don't see yet how it's related to creation of an array of CGColor objects.

Comment: How is it *not* related? It's the actual creation of an Array of CGColor. Without the need for an extension.

Comment: Which line shows an array of CGColor objects, please?  colors.map({ $0.CGColor }) ?

Comment: The variable `cgColors`  is an array of CGColors, as indicated by its type, `[CGColor]`.

Comment: Indeed...  That's interesting.  Thanks.

Comment: No problem. It's actually what @Martin R  suggested in one comment, I just noticed.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5+

You can convert `UIColor` array to `CGColor` array using: `colors.map { $0.cgColor }`

```
// example
let colors: [UIColor] = [.red, .green, .blue]
let cgColors = colors.map { $0.cgColor }
```